# what is "master/ (empty set mark)" in pink at IntelliJ package?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket, intellij-14

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PB007.png)

what is "master/ (empty set mark)" in pink at IntelliJ package?

should I delete it?

Comment: Looks like it's a Git project which is currently on the `master` branch. Should you delete Git projects? Probably not.

Comment: This feature is provided by [GitToolBox](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox) plugin. See "ahead / behind, current branch, tags on HEAD as Project View decoration on modules" from the plugin description